# Data Factory: Multiple collection reference for XML copy to SQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am attempting to set up a data factory pipeline which will ingest XML data to an Azure SQL Database. The XML follows this structure:

```
<schools>
    <school>
        <students>
            <student></student>
            <student></student>
            <student></student>
        </students>
    </school>
    <school>
        <students>
            <student></student>
            <student></student>
            <student></student>
        </students>
    </school>
<schools>
```

I've set up multiple tables in SQL to accept this data. Put simply, there is a schools table which will take all the schools and a students table to accept all the students.

I set up the copy task in data factory and had to set the "Collection reference" to `<school>` in order to get it to iterate over the schools. If I don't do this it only loads in the first school and ignores the rest.

This works just fine for loading in schools. The problem is with the next copy task which looks at the same XML and tries to copy all the students from all the schools into the students table.

If I set the collection reference to `<school>` it will only copy in the first student from every school and ignores the rest of the students. If I set the collection reference to `<student>` it will copy all the students in the first school but ignore the rest of the schools and students.

I'd like to iterate over ALL schools AND students in order to load in all students from all schools but I don't see any easy way to do this. Is there some way to set multiple collection references to both schools and students?

Comment: Data Factory only support choose one collection in the mapping setting for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does the XML come from?  I would take more of an ELT approach and land the XML in a staging table, then use the built-in XML capabilities of Azure SQL Database such as the `nodes` and `value` method.  A simplified example:

Similar JSON pattern using Web Activity and Stored Proc activity in ADF:

[image]

Sample SQL for importing XML:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.yourXMLStagingTable
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.student
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.school
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.yourXMLStagingTable (
    rowId       INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    yourXML     XML NOT NULL,
    dateAdded   DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    addedBy     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT SUSER_NAME()
    )
GO


CREATE TABLE dbo.school (
    schoolId    INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    schoolName  VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    )
GO


CREATE TABLE dbo.student (
    studentId   INT IDENTITY(1000,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    schoolId    INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.school(schoolId),
    studentName VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    )
GO


-- Use Data Factory to insert the data into a staging table
-- This is just to generate sample data
INSERT INTO dbo.yourXMLStagingTable ( yourXML )
SELECT '<schools>
    <school schoolName = "school1">
        <students>
            <student name = "student11"></student>
            <student name = "student12"></student>
            <student name = "student13"></student>
        </students>
    </school>
    <school schoolName = "school2">
        <students>
            <student name = "student21"></student>
            <student name = "student22"></student>
            <student name = "student23"></student>
        </students>
    </school>
</schools>'
GO

-- Look at the dummy data
SELECT * FROM dbo.yourXMLStagingTable
GO

-- Dump into a staging table
-- Get the schools
SELECT 
    s.rowId,
    schools.c.value('@schoolName', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS schoolName,
    students.c.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS studentName
INTO #tmp
FROM dbo.yourXMLStagingTable s
    CROSS APPLY s.yourXML.nodes('schools/school') schools(c)
        CROSS APPLY schools.c.nodes('students/student') students(c)


-- Look at the temp data
SELECT 'temp data' s, * FROM #tmp


-- Insert distinct schools data to schools table
INSERT INTO dbo.school ( schoolName )
SELECT DISTINCT schoolName
FROM #tmp


-- Insert distinct student data to student table, maintaining link to schools table
INSERT INTO dbo.student ( schoolId, studentName )
SELECT DISTINCT s.schoolId, t.studentName
FROM #tmp t
    INNER JOIN dbo.school s ON t.schoolName = s.schoolName
GO


-- End result
SELECT 'end result' s, *
FROM dbo.school school
    INNER JOIN dbo.student student ON school.schoolId = student.schoolId
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The origin of the XML is currently in Blob Storage. We have started to go down the path you recommended as it seemed like one of our only options. The only other I could think of is using an Azure Function to flatten the students out so I can iterate easily in Data Factory.

Comment: You could BULK INSERT directly from Blob Store into the staging table, go from there in the way I’ve described above.  Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: An update for you: I ended up having to do a combo of data factory, an azure function, and a stored procedure. I initially was trying to load the XML into SQL using data factory but it won't work with any XML files larger than 1 MB which is ridiculously low. We had data factory call an azure function which would retrieve the XML and then call a stored proc, passing the XML as a parameter, which would in turn load it into a staging table. Then we used SQL to shred the XML into each table. I'll accept since a ELT approach was the answer after all.